# how to display json data in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

I am passing ajax for getting data from database and also getting data in json format but I am unable display it on the view.
My ajax code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#inProgress").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          $.ajax({

          url: "inprogress",
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $("#token").attr('content'));
          },
          success: function(res) {

                  var i;
                  var txt = '';
                  res = $.parseJSON(res);
                  console.log(res);
                  $.each(res, function(index, element) {
                      txt += "<div align='center' class='row w3-card-2 vendor'  id='" + index + "'>" +
                          "kkdk"
                      "</div>";

                      $('#inProgressDiv').html(txt);

                      //console.log('<a href="'+element[0]+'">');
                  });

                  //
              } //success

          }); //ajax

     })

  });
```

Result i am getting following format from controller like this:

[image]

I want data in this format but how to display it. Please Help Me.

Comment: what you getting on the element value

Comment: it shows nothing for eg. element.firmName its shows nothing

Comment: console.log(element) what you get for this

Comment: you'r looping the wrong property, res has a property named as a date, that's the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below, you might want to tweak it a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#inProgress").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
          $.ajax({

          url: "inprogress",
          type: "POST",
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $("#token").attr('content'));
          },
          success: function(res) {

                  var i;
                  var txt = '';
                  res = $.parseJSON(res);
                  console.log(res);
                  foreach(var propname in res){
                   if($.isArray(res[propname]){
                         $.each(res, function(index, element) {
                              txt += "<div align='center' class='row w3-card-2 vendor'  id='" + index + "'>" +
                                  "kkdk"
                              "</div>";

                              $('#inProgressDiv').html(txt);

                              //console.log('<a href="'+element[0]+'">');
                          });
                   }
                  }
                  //
              } //success

          }); //ajax

     })

  });
```

Comment: Now I am able to access elements but now it is showing error for if statement used between display content

Comment: how to use if condition like this

Comment: var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 3) { break; }
    text += "The number is " + i + 
     if(i===2){ "This is two"+}

    "<br>";
}

Comment: It's syntax error, you can't concatenate a conditional block with a string, use ternary operator, ex: condition ? dowhentrue() : dowhenfalse()